# Integrating with iOS contacts

Tags: ios, contacts

I am currently programming an app which has a client database in it. I don't want to replicate all the name, address, email, phone (etc) data of the contacts in ios. Ideally, I would like to use my core data stack to store all of the additional information my app needs while allowing the contacts app in ios to handle all contact information. Is there a way to reference the contacts in ios using some unique ID at all so I can use that as a field in my core table client table?

Any advice/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ABAddressBook`, you can get the unique identifier by using `ABRecordGetRecordID(record)`